# CSS: Animate and slide images one after the other onto the screen?

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to animate and slide images onto the screen from right to left one after the other using CSS.

However, I can't seem to achieve this at all.

The images are just appearing all at the same time without any slide animation.

Here is my JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/npvsrkcy/

And my entire CSS code:

```
img {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin: 1em;
    animation: slide 4s 1;
  width:100%;
}
@keyframes slide {
    from { right: -150%; }
    to { left: 0%; }
}
```

Basically what I need to achieve is a smooth animation.

could someone please advise on this?

I can do this via jQuery but thats not the slide animation as I'm after and it doesn't look as smooth as CSS animation either.

This is the jQuery working version: http://jsfiddle.net/RSk7n/95/

Comment: It is all explained here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: @StefanGruenwald, i have no idea how that is related to my question but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes slide {
    from { right: -150%; }
    to { right: 0%; }
}
```

Comment: that slides all the images at the same time though.